# Не работает border-image

Tags: html, css

Ребята, есть такие правила пустого *div* селектора:

```
.round {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 27px;
-moz-border-image: url(bounces.png) 45 repeat;
-webkit-border-image: url(bounces.png) 45 repeat;
-o-border-image: url(bounces.png) 45 repeat;
border-image: url(bounces.png) 45 fill repeat;
}
```

По идее, *border* должен быть картинкой и растягиваться. Но, увы, он не повторяется.

Буду рад услышать решение проблемы.

Comment: а у меня работает Ваш код (вот смотрю на результат), картинки дублируются по краям и бокам. Картинка-то не слишком большая? Потренируйтесь создавать бордеры тут: http://border-image.com/

Comment: Я заходил на этот сервис и, по идее, сгенерированый сервисом код я вставил в редактор и пытался открыть через -webkit- -moz- -o-, но нигде нет нормального результата. Спасибо.

Comment: Хм. теперь использовал картинку с сайта, и все заработало. Может с картинкой что-то не так?

Comment: @dors, самое вероятное, что да, с картинкой что-то не так.